# .htaccess RewriteRule not working apache

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this link:
 
http://www.example.com/NEW/movie.php?name=Parker&id=1904996 
and i want it to display like this: 
http://www.example.com/NEW/Parker/1904996.htm

And this is my .htaccess code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /NEW/movie.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you have this rule in reverse in your code.

**Try these rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/NEW/.htaccess` file:**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /NEW/

# fix css/js/media links
RewriteRule ^.+?/((?:css|js|media)/.+)$ /$1 [R=302,NC,L,NE]

# remove spaces
RewriteRule "^([^ ]*) +(.*)$" $1$2 [L,R]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /movie\.php\?name=([^&]*)&id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2.htm? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+)\.html?$ movie.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L,NC,QSA,NE]
```

Comment: This one works, but it remove the NEW Directory from url. The url now becomes: http://www.movieking.me/Snitch/0882977.htm and now images and css are shown?

Comment: But you wrote: ` i want it to display like this: 
http://www.example.com/Parker/1904996.htm` Do you want it like: `http://www.example.com/NEW/Parker/1904996.htm` ?

Comment: Ans aldo i will need a solution when i will migrate from NEW directory to the root directory.

Comment: ok check edited code. Remember this goes in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/NEW/.htaccess file`

Comment: Added a rule for fixing css/js/media links. Ideally you should use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: still the same, i can not add absolute path now because there are a lot of images there

Comment: We seem to be solving a totally different problem than stated in the question. Try adding `<base href="/" />` on your HTML page in `<head>` section.

Comment: btw I tried `fix css/js/media` rule and it worked fine on my Apache.

Comment: where to put this rule fix css/js/media

Comment: Just below `RewriteBase /NEW/` line.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41656/discussion-between-axheladini-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 1):

`.html` means "any character followed by the literal string `html`. Yet you want it to be `.htm`. You can escape the period by putting a backslash in front of it.

- `.` = Any character
- `\.` = A literal `.` character

Perhaps use

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)\.html?$ /NEW/movie.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

Which would forward both `.html` and `.htm` (as the `l` should be "repeated 0 or 1 time").

Changes:

- `[^/]+` instead of `[^/]`. The plus means "repeated 1 or more times". If you don't have this, then you only allow **one** character that isn't a slash.
- `(.+)` instead of `[^/]`. Since we don't want it to keep matching until we reach a slash (as we won't reach a slash), we use the greedy term `.+` meaning "match as many characters as possible until you reach the next part (being `\.html?$`). We could also use `[^\.]` but that would mean that we couldn't use any periods in our ID.

Alternatively, if ID can only be a number:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([1-9][0-9]*)\.html?$ /NEW/movie.php?name=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

`[1-9][0-9]*` means "any digit between 1 and 9 followed by any digit between 0-9 repeated 0 to infinity times"

Comment: Still nothing, do i need to remove NEW/ if i put this file in same directory ?

Comment: Nothing website works as normal showing this url: http://www.example.com/NEW/movie.php?name=Parker&id=1904996

Comment: @AXheladini The htaccess will forward `example.com/asd/123.html` but it will not forward your old URL to your short-path - is that what you want?